# Duplicate entries in query with sum

Tags: postgresql

I have the following tables:

players: Columns: name, school_name, gender

double: Columns: player_name_fkey, school_name_fkey, category, tournament_number, score

My entries in the simple table will be similar to this. Each line is the score by a player at a specific tournament number.

```
Joe, Harvard, Junior, 1, 40
Joe, Harvard, Junior, 2, 30
Joe, Harvard, Junior, 3, 60
Anne, MIT, Senior, 1, 45
Anne, MIT, Senior, 2, 55
Anne, MIT, Senior, 3, 20 etc.
```

What I am looking to do is to get is, for each player, its total score over all tournaments. I then intent to select the best five players per school (which is why the partition command).

I have the following query:

```
SELECT player_name_fkey,
       school_name_fkey,
       sum_scores,
       rank() OVER (PARTITION BY school_name_fkey ORDER BY sum_scores DESC) AS scorerank
FROM (
  SELECT player_name_fkey,
         school_name_fkey,
         score,
         sum(score) AS sum_scores
  FROM double
    LEFT JOIN players ON players.name = double.player_name_fkey
  WHERE category = 'Benjamin'
    AND gender = 'Masculin'
    AND tournament_number >= 2
  GROUP BY player_name_fkey,
           school_name_fkey,
           score
) t1
GROUP BY t1.player_name_fkey,
         t1.school_name_fkey,
         t1.sum_scores;
```

I do get the correct sum for players, but unfortunately, I get an extra duplicate row for each player with a value of zero and I have no idea why.

Here is the code: http://rextester.com/XRRX92434

Thanks in advance for any help!

Benoit

Comment: Show us a reproducible example. With samples from both tables and the output you get. you can use https://rextester.com or https://sqlfiddle.com

Comment: There it is: http://rextester.com/XRRX92434

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple answer, you grouped by your sum.
Solution is simply to remove that from your group by statement, eg: http://rextester.com/EOH13219

```
SELECT player_name_fkey,
       school_name_fkey,
       sum_scores,
       rank() OVER (PARTITION BY school_name_fkey ORDER BY sum_scores DESC) AS scorerank
FROM (
  SELECT player_name_fkey,
         school_name_fkey,
         sum(score) AS sum_scores
  FROM double
    LEFT JOIN players ON players.name = double.player_name_fkey
  WHERE category = 'Benjamin'
    AND gender = 'Masculin'
    AND tournament_number >= 2
  GROUP BY player_name_fkey,
           school_name_fkey
) t1
GROUP BY t1.player_name_fkey,
         t1.school_name_fkey,
         t1.sum_scores;
```

Comment: You need to remove the `score` from the internal SELECT list, as you did in the linked rextester. And the `GROUP BY` in the external select is redundant.

Comment: nice catch @ypercubeᵀᴹ

Answer (score 3):

You don't need the derived table, you can use the window function to order by the sum.

The `LEFT JOIN` works as an `INNER JOIN` as columns from both tables appear in the `WHERE` clause, so it's probably better to explicitly state it as an inner join.

I added the `school_name` in the joining condition. It seems like it be there but it's not very clear in the question description. (Could a player be in one school and appear in a different school in the `double` table? The foreign key definition indicates that it can't.)

You state that you want *"for each player, its total score over **all tournaments**"* but the code has `WHERE tournament_number >= 2`. Which is correct?

```
SELECT d.player_name_fkey,
       d.school_name_fkey,
       sum(d.score) AS sum_scores,
       rank() OVER w AS scorerank
FROM players AS p 
    JOIN double AS d
    ON  p.name = d.player_name_fkey
    AND p.school_name = d.school_name_fkey
WHERE p.gender = 'Masculin' 
  AND d.category = 'Benjamin'
  AND d.tournament_number >= 2
GROUP BY d.player_name_fkey,
         d.school_name_fkey 
WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY d.school_name_fkey ORDER BY sum(d.score) DESC) ;
```